# How can I fix cross-origin error from Klarna iframe

Tags: cross-domain, klarna-widget

I have a Klarna Payments integration and in checkout when I load the Klarna iframe with

```
                           Klarna.Payments.load({
                             container: '#klarna-payments-pay-over-time',
                                           payment_method_category: 'pay_over_time'
                           },
                           function (res) {
                           console.debug(res);
                           });
```

I get a Cross-Origin Error:
"Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf https://sentry.io/api/85212/envelope/?sentry_key=.. "

I tried to add in Plesk Obsidian under additional headers this:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  or for better security (sentry.io),

but I still get this error. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to contact Klrana merchant support and request from them to add cross-origin permission to your domain and then maybe use a proxy mocking your domain for development